# Tool to easily create image maps

Tags: asp.net, html, image

I need to create an image map, but the shapes are quite complicated, and would take forever for me to do.

Is there any sort of tool that allows you to easily plot out the points for a map?

Comment: I posted a blog about the gimp tool: [http://weblogs.asp.net/stevewellens/archive/2011/02/02/create-image-maps-with-gimp.aspx](http://weblogs.asp.net/stevewellens/archive/2011/02/02/create-image-maps-with-gimp.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Gimp: http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Image_Map/ and http://docs.gimp.org/en/plug-in-imagemap.html

Answer (score 0):

There are some online tools - http://www.maschek.hu/imagemap/imgmap, http://dhost.info/eleomap, http://www.mobilefish.com/services/image_map/image_map.php

Answer (score 0):

This is actually the one place where it's still OK to use Dreamweaver. Creating complex image maps in DW is as simple as clicking around the outside of the shape to add points.